# How can I send a batch job to PBS using a function in Shell?

Tags: shell, batch-processing, jobs, pbs

I can submit a job to PBS using both approaches of Non-interactive Batch Jobs and/or Interactive Batch Jobs. However, I need to use the pbs commands in a function. In other world I need a structure like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
pbs_setup () {
 #PBS -l $1 
 #PBS -N $2
 #PBS -q normal                                         
 #PBS -A $USER                                                                                      
 #PBS -m ae                                                                                              
 #PBS -M $USER"@gmail.com"                                                                        
 #PBS -q normal
 #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
 #PBS
}    
pbs_setup "walltime=6:00:00" "step3";

echo " "
echo "Job started 
echo " "
echo "Job Ended
```

When I am submitting this job it is not working.

In fact my final goal is separating the commands of job from the main body of code. So when HPC will be changed I just edit a shell file which is included this function instead of editing all the shells. I appreciate if you give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with that job script is that the `#PBS` lines need to be *first* non-comment lines in the script file.

In my attempt to do this same concept, I used the same type of function you have, but `cat` the results and the actual commands into another file. i.e. An overarching script creates the 'job' script. You can put the HPC requirements in a separate file, then `source` it from the creation script.

*Edit in response to comment:*
e.g. 
To specify a path to start the job from:
`#PBS - d init_path`
"working directory path to be used for the job, PBS_O_INITDIR"

Or
`#PBS -D root_path`
"root directory to be used for the job, PBS_O_ROOTDIR."

Or
`#PBS -w working_path`
"If the -w option is not specified, the default working directory is the current directory. This option sets the environment variable PBS_O_WORKDIR."

So the default `PBS_O_WORKDIR` is the current directory you are IN when you call the script to submit the script to `qsub`.

Thus, if you set the specific options (d, D, w) for paths relative to the actual script running environment, you'll be able to use the paths you intend.

For specifics including default values of these and other options, you can check out the *man* page for your app. If using the Torque version of the PBS system, it's available at [linux.die.net - qsub](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qsub-torque)

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. With your suggestion I wrote down this code and it's working. However I have a problem with this line:

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR;
How we can deal with this line if code is in another directory than script.sh.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom submission command that collects the job options and sends them as command line parameters to actual `qsub` call.

Here is a rather basic example of this. In real usage I would add more sophisticated parameter handling tailored to the type of jobs, and more consistent with `qsub` interface. Also handling interactive jobs needs additional work.

1. submit.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   walltime="${2:-06:00:00}"
   name="${3:-step3}"
   queue="normal"
   acct="$USER"
   mailevents="ae"
   mailaddress="$USER@gmail.com"
   resources="nodes=1:ppn=8"        

   if [ $# -lt  1 ] ; then
      echo "Usage: submit.sh script [walltime [name]]" >
      exit 1
   fi

   script="$1"

   qsub -l "$walltime" -N "$name" -q "$queue" -A "$acct" \
        -m "$mailevents" -M "$mailaddress" -l "$resources" "$script"
   ```
2. script.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   echo " "
   echo "Job started" 
   echo " "
   echo "Job Ended"
   ```

This is supposed to be used as

```
    submit.sh script.sh 06:00:00 step3
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply. With your suggestion I wrote down this code and it's working. However I have a problem with this line:

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR;
How we can deal with this line if code is in another directory than script.sh.

Comment: @Sam if you are doing something like `submit.sh workdir/script.sh 06:00:00 step3`, then you can use the `dirname` and `basename` commands, i.e. in `submit.sh` do `cd $( dirname $script ) ; qsub ... $( basename $script )`